# $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n.\frac{1}{2^n} $ =?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

While solving a problem, I was able to get up to this step, but I can't progress any further. Please help me by saying what the value of the following will be: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n.\frac{1}{2^n} $$ 
P.S.: This sum is supposed to converge, isn't it?

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you prove that it converges, observe the following: one half of that sum is $\sum_{n\geq1}nt^n$ with $t=1/2$, and this is last series is $$t\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{n\geq1}t^n.$$

Comment: Really nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Remember

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} = \frac{ d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right) $$

In particular, if we can write

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2n \frac{1}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-1} $$

Comment: Awesome...:)
That helped.